# SQL Varchar Order

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Why when I have records like (`ratings = varchar`):

```
A - 100
B - 70
C - 30
```

Then:

```
SELECT * FROM `videos` ORDER BY `rating` DESC
```

Gives:

```
A - 30
B - 70
C - 100
```

And:

```
SELECT * FROM `videos` ORDER BY `rating` ASC
```

Gives:

```
A - 100
B - 70
C - 30
```

But when the (`ratings = tinyint`):

```
SELECT * FROM `videos` ORDER BY `rating` DESC
```

Gives:

```
A - 100
B - 70
C - 30
```

Comment: i cant see the difference between first and last query

Comment: i changed the rating column from varchar to tinyint, that fixed it. I want to know why.

Comment: aha sorry i didnt see it lmao.

Comment: your sample outputs don't make sense to me. Wouldn't A and B be reversed for your first two queries

Answer (score 2):

When you have a varchar column, the length of the text data and the fact the char '0' comes before char '1' (rather than after char '9') affects the sort order.

e.g. compare

```
select '100' as col1 
union all 
select '70' as col1
order by col1 asc
```

with

```
select '100' as col1 
union all 
select '070' as col1
order by col1 asc
```

You can get around this by suitably padding all strings to the same length.

Comment: So as varchar with 3 rows 100, 76, 22. What would DESC be and why? I sorta got what your saying.

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY rating, videos DESC
```

Comment: I already found the solution, I just want to know why when the column is varchar it don't work, and when its tinyint it works.